# Is the return statement and the end if the method required if the method return value is void?

Tags: objective-c, methods

If I have for example this piece of code:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
   // do whatever the method has to do
   return;
}
```

I know that the return is not required for the app to keep running. It seems to be smart enough to know that the method has finished. My question is: Does the absence of the return have negative side effects? (e.g. a memory leak)

---

Comment: NO! Not at all! Sometimes you can use it while testing, just to prevent line below return from executing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course not, `return` has no meaning in void methods except if you wanna return early based on condition or failure to stop execution rest of method.